# type OnProduce = extern "C" fn is not FFI safe

Tags: rust

```
pub type OnProduce = extern "C" fn(*mut ZLMedia, *const u8, size_t);
extern "C" {
    pub fn zlmedia_set_on_produce(zl_media: *mut ZLInstance, on_produce: OnProduce);
}
```

I get:

```
   |
23 |     pub fn zlmedia_set_on_produce(zl_media: *mut ZLInstance, on_produce: OnProduce);
   |                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^ not FFI-safe
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#[repr(C)]` or `#[repr(transparent)]` attribute to this struct
   = note: this struct has unspecified layout
```

but it's not possible to add `#[repr(C)]` for a type, only structs. As you can see, `OnProduce` is an `extern "C"` function. I thought it'd be already FFI-safe

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to replicate this lint in the Rust playground. Is this using clippy, and if so, do you have any non-default lints enabled?

Comment: I'm suspecting this is because `ZLMedia` isn't FFI-safe, so `extern "C" fn(*mut ZLMedia, ..)` isn't either. Hard to tell from info's in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frxstream pointed out, it's probably because `ZLMedia` isn't FFI-safe.

[Quote:](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-repr-c-necessary-for-rust-to-rust-ffi/50596/3?u=gretchenfrage)

> The trouble is that in Rust when a struct is repr(Rust) (the default) it is then free to use whatever layout it thinks is most efficient for your program. So this could (hypothetically) be different between two Rust programs and is even more likely to be different if the two programs are compiled with different versions of the Rust compiler.
>
> So for FFI you need an explicitly specified layout. Currently C and transparent are the only stable layouts for structs. There may be more more in the future but that's currently a ways off.

I recently had a discussion about this on the forums, which you might be interested to read (origin of the quote): [[link]](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-repr-c-necessary-for-rust-to-rust-ffi/50596)